# Abstract/Virtual Members to Provide Common & Derived Combined Functionality - C#

Tags: c#, .net, abstract-class, virtual-functions, abstract-methods

I've done this before - just can't remember the trick.

If i have an *abstract* class:

**public abstract class Post**

And a set of *deriving* classes:

**public class Photo : Post**

I want to **force** the deriving classes to implement a method called **Validate()**, but at the same time providing **core** validation at the **Post** level.

I can create a method: **public abstract void Validate()** in **Post**, which would force the deriving classes to implement the method, but then how do i perform the **Post** (base) validation?

The end result is i want to be able to do this:

```
public class BLL
{
   public void AddPost(Post post)
   {
       post.Validate(); // includes "Post" validation, any deriving validation.
       repository.Add(post);
   }
}
```

How can i do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is what you want:

```
public abstract class Post {

    // Default validation technique
    public void Validate()
    {
        // your base validation
        // Then call the specific validation technique
        ExtraValidate();
    }

    // Forces subclasses to provide validation technique
    protected abstract void ExtraValidate();
}
```

This will force base classes to implement a validation technique, and the base Validate will get called by external users.

It is impossible to make a method abstract, and provide a default implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Create a public template method in the base class and have it call the derived class validation method:

```
public abstract class Post {
    public void Validate() {
        // Post validation
        ValidateDerived();
    }

    protected abstract void ValidateDerived();
}
```

This forces derived classes to implement the method, but provides common validation logic for the Post class. Note that Validate() is not virtual itself. This is safer than forcing derived classes to have to remember to call base.Validate().

Comment: Is this different than my answer?

Comment: No difference. Your answer wasn't there when I started answering the question. I upvoted your answer to be polite.

Comment: I shall return the favor.  I didn't mean to sound rude either.  I was just curious if you meant something different than what I had posted.

Comment: I just upvoted both of your answers - just because of good manners!